# Sylius Generating CRUD routing with GRID, custom Repository & Actions

Tags: sylius

I'm using Sylius 1.0.0-dev

I created a custom "typed" Resource named manufactured_item.

- I need to create a custom backend Grid, displaying my Resource depending of it's type, thus I want to specify a custom repository method.
- I also need to create custom actions in main & item sections.

My configuration is the following:

```
app_production_manufactured_items:
resource: |
    alias: app.manufactured_item
    section: production
    templates: ProductionBundle:Crud
    only: ['index']
    grid: app_production_manufactured_items
    permission: true
    vars:
        all:
            subheader: sylius.ui.manage_your_orders
            templates:
                form: ProductionBundle:ManufacturedItem:_form.html.twig
        index:
            icon: cube
type: sylius.resource
```

I tryed to add something like this, but it does'nt work

```
#    defaults:
#        _sylius:
#            repository:
#                method: myCustomRepositoryMethod
```

I've read the in the [resource](http://dochttp://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/routing.html#generating-generic-crud-routing) the [grid](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/index.html) (freshly updated) and various thread in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700196/how-to-use-sylius-admin-crud-templates-with-sylius-resource-models/39713779#39713779) & Sylius repo, can't find a clue.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think you might have to override per route. app_manufactured_items_index:
    _sylius:
           repository: etc

Comment: I Brett, thanks for your help. I already tried this but I get an error "Unable to find template "/index.html.twig"". It seems it does not use the grid at all.  
  
I added the following:  
```app_production_manufactured_item_index:  
        path: /manufactured-items/  
        defaults:  
            _controller: app.controller.manufactured_item:indexAction  
            _sylius:  
                repository:  
                    method: myCustomRepositoryMethod```